# How can I fix Video not playing after installing Lubuntu on Chromebook?

Tags: lubuntu, video

So, I took the leap and decided to modify my old Chromebook by downloading special third-party firmware and deleting the Chrome OS from the machine. The version of Chrome OS I had was unsupported or would be in a few months, so this made sense, and I've run other OSes on Chromebooks before in Legacy Boot Mode, so I thought this wouldn't be much different.

Well, it looks like I was a little wrong. Since the install, I've been running into bugs. The latest being that videos don't play for more than a few minutes then there's this weird humming noise as the video buffers that doesn't stop until I close the video. It does this with every video. This is kind of a bummer because it means that I can't use this modified Chromebook for school/work in its current condition, which isn't a big deal in this particular case, because I have several laptops, but I'd like to see if I can get it working anyway or at least figure out what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

I'm running the latest version of Lubuntu (Kinetic Kudo) on what was a Lenovo N22 Touch Chromebook.

I'm relatively new to Linux and don't know how to find error logs for online videos or what files I'd need to look at. It does this with every online video, though, including streaming ones.

Edit: I decided to try installing a different version of Linux to see if that helps.

Comment: 1. Which version of Lubuntu are you using? 22.10? 22.04?
2. Can you edit the question and post the terminal output when the video crashes? E.g., run `vlc /path/to/video` and post the output.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the command to check why an online video crashed. I don't know the path to type in.

Comment: Your question did not say online video. If you are running Chromium/Firefox, run it from terminal, and post the output. Is the whole browser crashing or just the video?

Comment: It's just the video, and I'm not sure it wouldn't do it with local video, too, but I don't have local video saved to the computer.

Comment: You don't have to play a local video. Run the browser from terminal, play the online video, and post the output when the video crashes.

Comment: I ran Chrome from the browser, but I still don't know how to access a log of the error that occurred.

Comment: Run the command `google-chrome` in a terminal, reproduce the error by playing the video. Then, copy-paste the whole log from the terminal into the question.

Comment: I tried that. It did not give me a log.